# display images on all topic titles

Tags: php, image

I am trying to change this php code to display the image next to each title instead of the first title.

**Update code**:

```
global $cache;

$count_limit = 5;
$title_limit = 30;
$title_limit2 = 48;
$time_limit = 86400;
$forum_ids_arr = array(4,5,7,19,10,11); // separate with commas e.g. 1,2,3

@ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

if ( !empty($forum_ids_arr) ) {
foreach($forum_ids_arr as $fid) {
    $topic_with_img = array();
    $i = 0;

    while ( empty($topic_with_img) && $i < 20 ) {
        $sql = 'SELECT t.topic_id, t.topic_title, t.topic_poster,    t.topic_first_poster_name, t.topic_first_poster_colour, t.topic_replies, p.post_text, p.bbcode_uid, p.poster_id
                        FROM ' . TOPICS_TABLE . ' t
                  LEFT JOIN ' . POSTS_TABLE . ' p
                              ON t.topic_first_post_id = p.post_id
                    WHERE t.forum_id = ' . $fid . '
                                AND p.bbcode_uid <> ""
                    ORDER BY t.topic_time DESC';

        $result = $db->sql_query_limit($sql, $count_limit, $count_limit*$i, $time_limit);

        while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
            decode_message($row['post_text'], $row['bbcode_uid']);

            if ( strpos($row['post_text'], '[img]') === FALSE || strpos($row['post_text'], '[/img]') === FALSE ) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $row['post_text'] = " " . $row['post_text'];
              $ini = strpos($row['post_text'], "[img]");
              if ($ini == 0) {
                    $img_url = "";
                }
              $ini += strlen("[img]");
              $len = strpos($row['post_text'], "[/img]", $ini) - $ini;
              $img_url = substr($row['post_text'], $ini, $len);

                $topic_with_img['topic_id'] = $row['topic_id'];
                $topic_with_img['topic_title'] = $row['topic_title'];
                $topic_with_img['img_url'] = $img_url;


                $sql3 = 'SELECT forum_name
                                FROM ' . FORUMS_TABLE . '
                                WHERE forum_id = ' . $fid;
                $db->sql_query($sql3);
                $forum_name = $db->sql_fetchfield('forum_name');

                $topic_author_img       = get_username_string('full', $row['topic_poster'], $row['topic_first_poster_name'], $row['topic_first_poster_colour']);
                $topic_replies_img = ($auth->acl_get('is_registered', $topic_forum_id)) ? strval($row['topic_replies_real']) : strval($row['topic_replies']);
                $comment = (intval($topic_replies) == 1) ? $user->lang['TT_COMMENT'] : $user->lang['TT_COMMENTS'];
                $topic_replies_img .= $comment;

                $template->assign_block_vars('img_top_topic', array(
                    'TITLE'        => (strlen($row['topic_title']) > $title_limit) ? substr($row['topic_title'], 0, $title_limit).'…' : $row['topic_title'],
                    'U_LINK'  => append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}viewtopic.$phpEx", 't='.$row['topic_id']),
                    'IMG'     => $img_url,
                    'FORUM_NAME'  => $forum_name,
                    'FORUM_LINK'  => append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}viewforum.$phpEx", 'f='.$fid),
                    'TOPIC_AUTHOR_IMG'       => $topic_author_img,
                    'TOPIC_REPLIES_IMG'         => $topic_replies_img,
                ));

                $sql5 = 'SELECT t.topic_id, t.topic_title, t.topic_poster, t.topic_first_poster_name, t.topic_first_poster_colour, t.topic_replies, p.post_text, p.bbcode_uid, p.poster_id
                        FROM ' . TOPICS_TABLE . ' t
                  LEFT JOIN ' . POSTS_TABLE . ' p
                              ON t.topic_first_post_id = p.post_id
                    WHERE t.forum_id = ' . $fid . '
                                AND p.bbcode_uid <> ""
                    ORDER BY t.topic_time DESC';
                    $result2 = $db->sql_query_limit($sql5, $count_limit - 1, 1, $time_limit);


                while ($row2 = $db->sql_fetchrow($result2)) {
                    decode_message($row2['post_text'], $row2['bbcode_uid']);

                if ( strpos($row2['post_text'], '[img]') === FALSE || strpos($row2['post_text'], '[/img]') === FALSE ) {
                continue;
                } else {

                    $row2['post_text'] = " " . $row2['post_text'];
              $ini1 = strpos($row2['post_text'], "[img]");
              if ($ini1 == 0) {
                    $img_url1 = "";
                }
              $ini1 += strlen("[img]");
              $len1 = strpos($row2['post_text'], "[/img]", $ini1) - $ini1;
              $img_url1 = substr($row2['post_text'], $ini1, $len1);

                $topic_with_img1['topic_id'] = $row2['topic_id'];
                $topic_with_img1['topic_title'] = $row2['topic_title'];
                $topic_with_img1['img_url'] = $img_url1;


                $sql4 = 'SELECT forum_name
                                FROM ' . FORUMS_TABLE . '
                                WHERE forum_id = ' . $fid;
                $db->sql_query($sql4);
                $forum_name1 = $db->sql_fetchfield('forum_name');

                    $topic_author       = get_username_string('full', $row2['topic_poster'], $row2['topic_first_poster_name'], $row2['topic_first_poster_colour']);
                    $topic_replies = ($auth->acl_get('is_registered', $topic_forum_id)) ? strval($row2['topic_replies_real']) : strval($row2['topic_replies']);
                    $comment = (intval($topic_replies) == 1) ? $user->lang['TT_COMMENT'] : $user->lang['TT_COMMENTS'];
                    $topic_replies .= $comment;

                  $template->assign_block_vars('img_top_topic.last_top_topics', array(
                        'TITLE'        => (strlen($row2['topic_title']) > $title_limit2) ? substr($row2['topic_title'], 0, $title_limit2).'…' : $row2['topic_title'],
                        'TOPIC_AUTHOR'       => $topic_author,
                        'TOPIC_REPLIES'         => $topic_replies,  
                        'U_LINK'  => append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}viewtopic.$phpEx", 't='.$row2['topic_id']),
                        'LAST_IMG'     => $img_url1,
                    ));
                    }
                }
                $db->sql_freeresult($result2);

                break;

            }
        }
        $db->sql_freeresult($result);

        if (empty($topic_with_img)) {
            $cache->destroy('sql');
        }

        $i++;
    }
}
}
```

I was able to get the outcome I want, but is there a way to simplify this code above? All i did was duplicate the top part of the code with the bottom part.

Here is the new outcome of this code:

http://i1056.photobucket.com/albums/t365/iamthestreets/img_zps5732c7ed.png

Here is the new outcome of this code:

http://i1056.photobucket.com/albums/t365/iamthestreets/newimg_zps36fdd004.png

I want every title to have an image next to it.

I am not asking for someone to write the code (unless you want too), but someone to help me figure it out. I am still very new to PHP.

Edit:
Here is the HTML

```
<div class="tt">
<!-- BEGIN img_top_topic -->
<div class="tt_column<!-- IF img_top_topic.S_ROW_COUNT == 0 or     img_top_topic.S_ROW_COUNT == 3 --> one<!-- ELSEIF img_top_topic.S_ROW_COUNT == 1 or img_top_topic.S_ROW_COUNT == 4 --> two<!-- ELSEIF img_top_topic.S_ROW_COUNT == 2 or img_top_topic.S_ROW_COUNT == 5 --> three<!-- ENDIF -->">
    <h3 <!-- IF img_top_topic.S_ROW_COUNT > 2 -->style="margin-top: 20px;"<!-- ENDIF -->><a href="{img_top_topic.FORUM_LINK}">{img_top_topic.FORUM_NAME}</a></h3>


        <ul>
        <div class="imgresize"><a href="{img_top_topic.U_LINK}"><img src="{img_top_topic.IMG}" alt="{img_top_topic.TITLE}" /></a></div>
        <li class="one"><a class="img_title" href="{img_top_topic.U_LINK}">{img_top_topic.TITLE}</a></li>
        <li class="topic_title_span"><span>by {img_top_topic.TOPIC_AUTHOR_IMG} |{img_top_topic.TOPIC_REPLIES_IMG}</span></li>
        </ul>


    <!-- BEGIN last_top_topics -->
        <ul>
        <div class="imgresize"><a href="{last_top_topics.U_LINK}"><img src="{last_top_topics.LAST_IMG}" alt="{last_top_topics.TITLE}" /></a></div>
        <li class="one"><a class="img_title" href="{last_top_topics.U_LINK}">{last_top_topics.TITLE}</a></li>
        <li class="topic_title_span"><span>by {last_top_topics.TOPIC_AUTHOR} |{last_top_topics.TOPIC_REPLIES}</span></li>
        </ul>

    <!-- END last_top_topics -->        

</div>
```

Comment: can you do a var_dump($img_url) in your code and see if your code is generating a valid image url for all the cases ?

Comment: I get a bunch of random text like this: string(122) "http://newsbcpcol.stb.s-msn.com/amnews/i/a2/4613d261b9c1d1b90fe7a413f9f/_h353_w628_m6_otrue_lfalse.jpg" string(122) "http://newsbcpcol.stb.s-msn.com/amnews/i/a2/4613d261b9c1d1b90fe7a413f9f/_h353_w628_m6_otrue_lfalse.jpg" string(122) "http://newsbcpcol.stb.s-msn.com/amnews/i/a2/4613d261b9c1d1b90fe7a413f9f/_h353_w628_m6_otrue_lfalse.jpg" string(122) "http://newsbcpcol.stb.s-msn.com/amnews/i/a2/4613d261b9c1d1b90fe7a413f9f/_h353_w628_m6_otrue_lfalse.jpg" string(122)

Comment: does that look like valid image url to you? what happens when you click on those ?

Comment: Yes, it does. when I pasted it into this comment it striped out the some text. If you click on this link it will open an image. [link]http://newsbcpcol.stb.s-msn.com/amnews/i/a2/4613d261b9c1d1b90fe7a413f9f/_h353_w628_m6_otrue_lfalse.jpg

Comment: Can anyone help me with this. I have tried so many different things and cannot get it to work.

Comment: is this all the code that you have or is there something else ? what does $template->assign_block_vars do ?

Comment: can you also post the html code that is rendered from your php code? That is what the browser is using to display the page and it might be easier to debug this using the html code.

Comment: $template->assign_block_vars is to use in the HTML. This is for a phpBB forum.

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: so it is working for you now then ?

Comment: it's working, but i want to simplify the code. I know it does not have to be as complex as it is, but i can't figure it out.

Comment: If the code that you have posted above is all the code that you have then I don't think there is a lot of scope for simplification unless you want to re-write your complete logic. The code above looks simplified enough to me (there might still be scope for improvements here though)